# VSTS-Build (git): tag source code at the end of the build

Tags: git, build, tags, azure-devops

I have the following problem:

a builddefinition requires that the sourcecode in the repository is tagged, the tag that should be used looks like this: "$(build.major).$(build.minor).$(build.ticker)"

the first 2 variables can are variables that are set when queuing, the third one is calculated during the buildprocess. Because of it beeing calculated during the build, i can not use the configurable option from VSTS to tag my build. VSTS won't resolve this variable and i end up with tags like "1.2.$(build.ticker)"

Is there any other way to tag my source code at the end of the build ?

Comment: You could still call the 'git tag' command to create your tag and after that, push it...

Comment: i can't push the tag from inside the build-process unfortunately :/

Comment: Could you explain a little more why you can't tag within the build process?  VSTS isn't limited against this.

Comment: the push command ('git push origin --tags') is running indefinitely. runs an hour and then the build gets cancelled due to timeout

Comment: @D.J. I'll bet $$ the timeout is a popup authentication prompt.  You can't just call "git push origin --tags", you'll additionally need to provide authentication.  The solution will be dependent on where you are getting your sources from.  If you are "git push" in a poweshell script try this (Also you'll need to enable the option "Allow scripts to access OAuth token")  git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $Env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" push origin --tags

Comment: This actually worked, i had then the issue that my buildservice wasn't allow to contribute but now this works :) can you pls post this as an "Answer" so that i can accept this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout is a popup authentication prompt. You can't just call "`git push origin --tags`", you'll additionally need to provide authentication. The solution will be dependent on where you are getting your sources from. If you are "git push" in a poweshell script try this (Also you'll need to enable the option "Allow scripts to access OAuth token") `git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $Env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" push origin --tags`

Answer by @raterus, he didn't post it as answer so i am going to post it and mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Git, I would recommend using the [GitVersion task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion#overview) , it will do semantic versioning of your builds automatically.  There is no reason to roll out your own solution.

You may want to look at [Mainline mode](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/mainline-development/) (a newer feature), this will increment the "build ticker" for you on each commit.

Comment: i don't have a problem with versioning, my problem is that i want to create a git-tag during the build.
The task you suggested does not tag :/